# Programatically importing library to workspace in Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I would like to programatically add a (Python Wheel) library to the `/Shared` workspace on Databricks. It is easy to do in the GUI (Workspace > Import > Library), but I cannot figure out how to do it in the Databricks CLI.

So I though that I had two possible strategies:

1. Install it as a library
2. Copy it as a file to the workspace

It seems that 1) is not feasible because the *library* term is dedicated to actual installations on clusters, while 2) is not feasible because `workspace import` requires languages (Python, R, SQL, etc.), and interprets the files as scripts.

So I am a bit lost on how to approach this.

Answer (score 3):

As per my observation:

**Note:** `databricks workspace import` "Imports a file from local to the Databricks workspace."

I have tried with `databricks workspace import` cmdlets and understood that it copies as a file.

[image]

> How to install a library using Azure Databricks CLI?

**Copy the library from local directory to DBFS using DBFS CLI:**

```
databricks fs cp "C:\Users\Azurewala\Downloads\wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl" dbfs:/FileStore/jars
```

**Create a cluster using the API or UI.**

Get cluster id using `databricks clusters list` and cop the cluster-id.

**Attach the libraries in DBFS to a cluster using DBFS CLI:**

```
databricks libraries install --cluster-id "0802-090441-honks846" --whl "dbfs:/FileStore/jars/wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl"
```

[image]

Successfully installed a library using Azure Databricks CLI:

[image]

Hope this helps.