# Can we store a .whl file in a the Databricks workspace?

Tags: python, azure, devops, databricks, workspace

In our Azure DevOps build+release pipeline, we [push our Python code to Databricks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DataThirstLtd.databricksDeployScriptsTasks) using .whls. Right now, we push our .whl files to `/dbfs/FileStore/libs`.

**Can we also push .whl files to the Databricks Workspace (programatically, using Azure DevOps)?** This is where I'd like to put it (`/Models`):
[image]
I'm asking because one of our clients needs to set permissions on (which users can read) the .whl files in Databricks. This kind of access control is only possible for folders and files in the Workspace - not on the `dbfs`.

I've tried to create a [workspace library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/workspace-libraries#--upload-a-jar-python-egg-or-python-wheel) via the UI. That action (visually) results in a .whl in the Workspace, but the .whl is stored on the `dbfs` anyway. Via the UI, importing a .whl to the Workspace is not possible:

> Accepted formats: .dbc, .scala, .py, .sql, .r, .ipynb, .Rmd, .html, .zip

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can refer to [Programatically importing library to workspace in Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002541/programatically-importing-library-to-workspace-in-databricks)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT thanks! The comment explains how to install a library via dbfs, which is precisely what I _don't_ want. `databricks workspace import ...` (i.e. the cli) doesnt't accept .whls.

Answer (score 1):

Databricks workspace supports importing only of source code (Scala/Python/R) that is stored inside Databricks control plane - it doesn't make sense to store binary files in the control plane because they won't be accessible by Python process that runs inside the data plane (your environment).  The only exception is Databricks Repos that has support for [arbitrary files](https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html#enable-support-for-arbitrary-files-in-databricks-repos), but even with that it's harder to use that library.

What you can use is so-called [workspace libraries](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/workspace-libraries.html) that allow to create an object in the UI to represent your library so it could be selected from the cluster, etc.  But the actual binary will be still on DBFS/PyPi, etc.

Comment: @AlexQtt  aha! If the files won't be accessibe, then there's no point in trying;). Thanks for the clarification!