# How to install a library in Databricks usind databricks cli?

Tags: azure-databricks

I am new in databricks.

I have a questions like stackoverflow's question 57002541 ( programatically-importing-library-to-workspace-in-databricks)

*[Programatically importing library to workspace in Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002541/programatically-importing-library-to-workspace-in-databricks)*

I did the procedure that CHEEKATLAPRADEEP describe, but the last command did't work.

The files that I get are:

```
$ databricks fs ls dbfs:/FileStore/jars
9a69207e_9495_4698_b499_26bf95d4b4d0-spark_examples_2_11_2_4_7_7_1_7_2010_1-09e83.jar
kudu-spark3-tools_2.12-1.15.0.7.1.7.2010-1.jar
```

The first file was loaded by WebUI and the second one was loaded by cli ( **databricks fs cp** ), but the second is not seen in the WebUI

I want to load the *kudu-spark3-tools_2.12-1.15.0.7.1.7.2010-1.jar*
into the cluster ***1023-124341-ftg82vdr***

I load the first library by WebUI, and it can see it by:

```
$ databricks libraries cluster-status 1023-124341-ftg82vdr
[
  {
    "is_library_for_all_clusters":false,
    "library": {
      "jar":"dbfs:/FileStore/jars/9a69207e_9495_4698_b499_26bf95d4b4d0-spark_examples_2_11_2_4_7_7_1_7_2010_1-09e83.jar"
    },
    "status":"PENDING"
  }
]
```

but using the command described in questions 57002541, I get an error:

```
$ databricks libraries install cluster_id 1024-073005-4p2jnzfl  jar dbfs:/FileStore/jars/kudu-spark3-tools_2.12-1.15.0.7.1.7.2010-1.jar
Error: please provide command input in JSON format by specifying the --json flag
```

So I try to create a json but I haven't been able to do it yet.

My json is:

```
{
 "name": "Test install library",
 "cluster_id": "1023-124341-ftg82vdr",
 "tasks": [
     {
     "library": [
       {
         "workspace": {
           "jar": "dbfs:/FileStore/jars/kudu-spark3-tools_2.12-1.15.0.7.1.7.2010-1.jar"
       }
     }
  ]
}
]
}
```

And the error that I get is:

```
$ databricks libraries install --json @librarySparkDatabricks.json 
Error: Invalid installation request with no libraries to be installed on cluster 1023-124341-ftg82vdr
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error

the correct json is:

```
{
  "name": "spark_examples_2_11_2_4_7_7_1_7_2010_1.jar",
  "cluster_id": "1023-124341-ftg82vdr",
     "libraries": [
       {
           "jar": "dbfs:/FileStore/jars/kudu-spark3-tools_2.12-1.15.0.7.1.7.2010-1.jar"
       }
    ]
}
```